# how to see the code fo a matlab mex file

Tags: matlab

I have a mex file but not the C code it was compiled from. Is there any way I can see the code from the mex file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mex file, as its name suggests, is a **m**atlab **ex**ecutable file. It's compiled using a C compiler and unless you know how to reverse engineer executables, I don't think you can get the initial C source code back.